# Error initializing ArrayList

Tags: java, object, tokenize

```
public class driver 
{
private static ArrayList<String> arrayList ;
TownBankRecord TBR = new TownBankRecord();
ArrayList<Record> TBList = new ArrayList<Record>();

public void getDate()
{
try 
{

   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("data/bank-data.csv"));
   String line= " ";
   int tokenCount=0;
   //BankRecord bank= new BankRecord();

    while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
         if (!line.equals(","))
         {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
            while (st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                arrayList.add(st.nextToken());
                tokenCount++;
            }
         }

         if (tokenCount==11)
         {
            er = new TownBankRecord(arrayList);
            TBList.add(er);

            tokenCount=0;
         }
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } 
catch (IOException e) 
{
     System.err.println("Caught IOException: " 
                         +  e.getMessage());

}
}
}
```

The above code reads from a CSV file. I have used a tokenizer which gets the tokens from each line and then transfers them to an ArrayList of Strings. The ArrayList is then transfered to an object `er` of TownBankRecord which then finally transfered to TBlist (Record datatype). I have the following error for er:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable er
location: class nidhin.driver.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you going to accept an answer? You have three excellent, correct answers. You don't have to accept mine, even, just because it's the highest voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never declare `er` as a variable. You also don't use the class field you do declare, `TBR`. Are these intended to be the same?

Comment: Yes , er is never declared , initially , there will be nothing in er , as for TBR , i will use this later on in the program

Comment: TownBankRecord er = new TownBankRecord(arrayList);

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
er = new TownBankRecord(arrayList);
TBList.add(er);
```

to this:

```
TBList.add(new TownBankRecord(arrayList));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have not declared `er` anywhere. You can declare `er` in the class as a member. You can also declare `er` in the method `getDate()`, just make sure you initialize `er` before using it. It completely depends upon your requirements. I can see that you have made `arrayList` static. If you are reading the same file again and again then there is no need to make `arrayList` a static variable and the best practice is to declare it in method rather than as class member.